# How/why did the layout of a medieval village change over time?

Tags: construction, medieval, infrastructure

Within the medieval era, I'm interested in knowing what sort of rules or reasons caused **the layout** to change from sparse rural villages with a few houses (lots of farmland) to dense sprawling city with a castle and walls. And what was this process like?

How did they go from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

### Possible sub-questions

- What decided where the castle was placed?
- Was the layout circular or more square and why?
- Why did the layout get more dense instead of just bigger since there was so much land around?
- Were there some kind of continental reasons people followed? Like:

  - When a land owner dies, their area will be split between the children (causing building density to naturally rise over time)
- Did people construct roads first and houses around them or the other way around?
- How did materials change depending on a village growing? (did buildings closer to the center adopt stone etc..)

Is it just me or is it really difficult to find information on this stuff :/ Closest thing I could find was this article which touched on population density, city populations, and some other partly related topics.

https://medium.com/migration-issues/notes-on-medieval-population-geography-fd062449364f

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. As the name suggests, we solve problems related to building fictional worlds. Your questions seems to be asking about plain history, which belongs to another SE community. Moreover, there are too many questions in a single post. More info in the [help]

Comment: Yeah maybe you're right, I was also planning on posting in history SE after this. Though I would also say that there are almost 700 questions tagged 'medieval' here (which is about the same as history SE) with a lot of them not necessarily having a non-fictional element to them. So I was interested if the knowledge in this community had any insight as well

Comment: Again from the [help]: Please do not cross-post questions to multiple Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: (1) A manor is not a castle. (2) They did not go from the first picture to the second, or, if they ever did, it was exceedingly rare, because .... (3) villages do agriculture, cities do commerce. They don't mix. (4) There are many many many books about the history of various cities. Pick a city, search for "history of <city name>" on Archive.org. (Ah, and the first picture is in the nature of a diorama, illustrating how a feudal domain worked. It is not not not intended to represent the actual physical layout of a medieval village.)

Comment: @AlexP Thanks! That is a lot more insightful about what I should do next (rather than a sort of 'go away' response)! These are the kind of responses I was looking for. Is there any cities you would recommend?

Comment: Don't know. It depends on what exact Middle Ages you are interested in. (Hint: north-western European Middle Ages, the thing with feudal hierarchy etc. is quite unique. Mediterranean Middle Ages was different. Eastern European Middle Ages was different. Byzantine and Ottoman Middle Ages was *very* different. Persian, Indian, Chinese etc. Middle Ages are as different as humans can make them.) If stereotypical north-western European Middle Ages is your thing, look up the history of London, or Paris, or Amsterdam, etc.

Comment: That's awesome and super useful, thanks so much for this! I will read about the history of those cities as well as details about the north-western European Middle Ages before making any more posts.

Comment: Re circular or square, consider if and when it was fortified. Roman camp vs. medieval curtain wall vs. Vauban-style fortress.